# How to send a push notification without sound?

Tags: quickblox

I can send Push Notifications from QB Admin with no sound. How do I do the same when sending a push notification from my device/app? Just omit the sound key?

```
NSString *mesage = @"Hello man!";
NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *aps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
// [aps setObject:@"default" forKey:QBMPushMessageSoundKey]; // just omit this line?
[aps setObject:mesage forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertKey];
[payload setObject:aps forKey:QBMPushMessageApsKey];

QBMPushMessage *message = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];

// Send push to users with ids 292,300,1295
[QBMessages TSendPush:message toUsers:@"292,300,1395" delegate:self];
```

Also, is there a limit for the number of ID's in the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just omit this line.

No limits of the number of ID's. But if you have many IDs, you can also use Tags

Comment: Thanks Igor. We wanted to use CHECK-IN (createGeodata) with PUSH NOTIFICATION from LOCATION, but there is no parameter to avoid the notification sound. As the control over these notification is limited (it depends on user's check-ins) we're doing it "manually" so we can send the notifications with no sound (less intrusive).

Maybe you could add a SOUND parameter to CHECK-IN with PUSH NOTIFICATION in the future.